# RDP client for Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, rdp

I'm looking for a RDP client that I can install and run on Amazon Linux 2 to connect to other EC2 instances through xrdp. I've tried remmina with no luck.

Does anyone know of an RDP client that will work on Amazon Linux 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found FreeRDP. It works well on Amazon Linux 2.
https://www.freerdp.com/